# PHP Select won't return all data

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I am doing one page into this test site and I want that all usernames stored into MySQL database be displayed to the administrator so him could edit/exclude them.

I have this code until now:

```
<?php 
        $sql = "SELECT cdUsuario from tbUsuario";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,1);
        print_r($row);
        ?>
        <form>
            <select name="selecting">
                <?php
                    foreach($row as $key)
                    {
                        ?><option value="<?php echo $key;?>"><?php echo $key; ?></option><?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </form>
```

The problem is:
Does not matter how much rows I add into database, it Always returns just the first username.
As a test I did an print_r($row) and the return is always

```
Array ( [cdUser] => firstUsername )
```

Comment: You only fetched one row: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: Read manual `mysqli_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative` __Row__, not __Rows__

Comment: I was missing that! Thank you, solved my problem extremely fast!

Comment: Why not use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and use a while loop instead of  foreach?

Answer (score 1):

[`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns a single row as an array of its columns. To get all the rows, you need to iterate and call `mysqli_fetch_array` as long as it returns data:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, 1) != null) {
    # Handle the current row
    # ...
```